# Neo4j JDBC driver - SystemException Error in processing event for DatabaseWriter {Method getPrimaryKeys} not implemented

Tags: jdbc, neo4j

Trying to write to Neo4J database in an ETL scenario, sourcing from SQL Server and writing to Neo4J.

Mapping of Source to Target - dbo.EMP, n:Emp

1. Created a node in Neo4J as follows
   CREATE (n:Emp { empId: '500', empDept: 'Sales', empFname: 'STUART', empLname: 'WOODS' })
2. Created a constraint as follows
   CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Emp) ASSERT n.empId IS UNIQUE;

On execution with the Neo4J 3.3.1 JDBC driver, I am getting an error

> Error in processing event for DatabaseWriter {Method getPrimaryKeys in
>   class org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jDatabaseMetaData is not yet implemented.}

Is the `getPrimaryKeys` not implemented in the current release of Neo4J JDBC writer?

Comment: That's what it says, isn't it?

Comment: Why are you asking a question that is answered by the error message itself?

Comment: The Neo4J JDBC driver download site suggested using Stack Overflow to ask questions or to request enhancements.